# Wildcard search on specific terms using MultiFieldQueryParser

Tags: lucene.net, wildcard

I am utilizing the Lucene.net version 3.0 API to create and search an index for my project. Each Document in my index has three Fields:

- TransactionId
- Agent
- Lender

My requirements are this:

1. I want a hit if a search term matches the *first part* of a Document's
   value for **TransactionId**. For example, if I search for "ab" then
   Documents with **TransactionId** equal to "ab-1" or "ab-2" would be
   hits.
2. I only want hits when the *full search term* matches **Agent** and **Lender**.
       The search for "ab" would *not* return Documents where the value of
       Lender is "ab-1" or "ab-2".

So far, I have the following block of code:

```
var searcher = new IndexSearcher(FSDirectory.Open(path));
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, 
 new[] {"TransactionId", "Agent", "Lender"},
 new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30));

var query = parser.Parse(queryText);
var hits = searcher.Search(query, 200);
```

If `queryText` is "ab" then the value of query is `{TransactionId:ab Agent:ab Lender:ab}`

I know I am looking for it to be something like `{TransactionId:ab* Agent:ab Lender:ab}`

Is there any way to do this with the `MultiFieldQueryParser`?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably achieve that by subclassing the `MultiFieldQueryParser`.

The following seems to works, maybe something you can build on. Note that parsing the BooleanQuery should be recursive as you could end up with nested queries eventually.

**Disclaimer: this code isnt elegant and probably breaks very easily as is, its intended as a quick example**

```
    public class WildCardForFieldQueryParser : MultiFieldQueryParser
    {
        public WildCardForFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version version, 
                                           string [] fields, 
                                           Analyzer analyzer, 
                                           HashSet<string> wildcardFields)
            :base(version, fields, analyzer)
        {
            this._wildcardFields = wildcardFields;
        }

        public override Query Parse(string query)
        {
            // clause replacement should be recursive
            Query q = base.Parse(query);
            if (q is BooleanQuery)
            {
                foreach (var clause in q as BooleanQuery)
                {
                    if (clause.Query is TermQuery && this._wildcardFields.Contains(((TermQuery)clause.Query).Term.Field))
                    {
                        clause.Query = new PrefixQuery(new Term(((TermQuery)clause.Query).Term.Field, ((TermQuery)clause.Query).Term.Text));
                    }
                }
            }
            return q;
        }
        private HashSet<string> _wildcardFields;
    }
```